# Read pixels from 1bpp bitmap (CreateDIBSection)

Tags: c++, winapi

This code works fine for 32, 24, 16, 8, 4 bpp images. But not for 1 bpp.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "user32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "gdi32.lib")

void GetWindowBitmapBitsAndSave(const HWND& hWnd, int nBitCount, char *szFilePath);
void EnumerateBits(LPBYTE pBits, int nBitCount, int nWidth, int nHeight);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    //GetWindowBitmapBits(HWND_DESKTOP, 32);
    //32, 24, 16, 8, 4 works fine...
    GetWindowBitmapBitsAndSave(HWND_DESKTOP, 1, "test.bmp");

    return 0;
}

void EnumerateBits(LPBYTE pBits, int nBitCount, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    int nPixels = nWidth * nHeight; 
    WORD wByteCount = nBitCount / 8; 
    if(wByteCount == 0)
        wByteCount = 1;
    int nBytes = nPixels * wByteCount; 

    for(int i = 0; i < nBytes; i += wByteCount) 
    { 
        int r = (int)(*(pBits+i));
        //int g = (int)(*(pBits+i+1));
        //int b = (int)(*(pBits+i+2));

        //just for test
        if(r != 0 /*&& g != 0 && b != 0*/)
            if(r != 255 /*&& g != 255 && b != 255*/)
            //printf("(%d, %d, %d)\n", r, g, b);
                    printf("%d\n", r);
    } 
}

void GetWindowBitmapBitsAndSave(const HWND& hWnd, int nBitCount, char* szFilePath)
{
    HWND hScreenWnd = hWnd;
    if(!hScreenWnd)
        hScreenWnd = HWND_DESKTOP;

    //calculate the number of color indexes in the color table
    int nColorTableEntries = -1;
    switch(nBitCount) 
    {
        case 1:
            nColorTableEntries = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            nColorTableEntries = 16;
            break;
        case 8:
            nColorTableEntries = 256;
            break;
        case 16:
        case 24:
        case 32:
            nColorTableEntries = 0;
            break;
        default:
            nColorTableEntries = -1;
            break;
    }

    if(nColorTableEntries == -1)
    {
        printf("bad bits-per-pixel argument\n");
        return;
    }

    HDC hDC = GetDC(hScreenWnd);
    HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

    int nWidth = 0;
    int nHeight = 0;

    if(hScreenWnd != HWND_DESKTOP)
    {
        RECT rect;
        GetClientRect(hScreenWnd, &rect);
        nWidth = rect.right - rect.left;
        nHeight = rect.bottom - rect.top;
    }
    else
    {
        nWidth = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
        nHeight = ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    }


    HBITMAP hBMP = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, nWidth, nHeight);
    SelectObject(hMemDC, hBMP);
    BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    int nStructLength = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * nColorTableEntries;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER BitmapInfoHeader;

    BitmapInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    BitmapInfoHeader.biWidth = nWidth;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biHeight = nHeight;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biBitCount = nBitCount;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biClrUsed = nColorTableEntries;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biClrImportant = nColorTableEntries;

    DWORD dwBytes = ((DWORD) nWidth * nBitCount) / 32;
    if(((DWORD) nWidth * nBitCount) % 32) {
        dwBytes++;
    }
    dwBytes *= 4;

    DWORD dwSizeImage = dwBytes * nHeight;
    BitmapInfoHeader.biSizeImage = dwSizeImage;

    BITMAPINFO* bitmapInfo = new BITMAPINFO[sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * nColorTableEntries];
    bitmapInfo->bmiHeader = BitmapInfoHeader;

    if(nBitCount < 16)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i != nColorTableEntries; ++i)
        {
            bitmapInfo->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = 
                bitmapInfo->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen =
                bitmapInfo->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = (BYTE)(i*(255/(nColorTableEntries-1)));
            bitmapInfo->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = 0;
        }
    }

    LPBYTE lpDibBits = 0;
    HBITMAP hBitmap = ::CreateDIBSection(hMemDC, bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void**)&lpDibBits, NULL, 0);
    SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    ReleaseDC(hScreenWnd, hDC);

    //save bitmap
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;
    bmfh.bfType = 0x4d42;  // 'BM'
    int nHeaderSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * nColorTableEntries;
    bmfh.bfSize = 0;
    bmfh.bfReserved1 = bmfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bmfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + sizeof(RGBQUAD) * nColorTableEntries;    

    FILE *pFile = 0;
    fopen_s(&pFile, szFilePath, "wb");
    if(pFile)
    {
        fwrite(&bmfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, pFile);
        fwrite(bitmapInfo, nHeaderSize,1,pFile);
        fwrite(lpDibBits, dwSizeImage, 1, pFile);
        fclose(pFile);
    }

    EnumerateBits(lpDibBits, nBitCount, nWidth, nHeight);

    delete[]bitmapInfo;
    ::DeleteObject(hBMP);
    ::DeleteObject(hBitmap);
}
```

First question: Why when bit count is 1 there are colors other than black and white? (but image is monochrome. Just comment EnumerateBits call in GetWindowBitmapBitsAndSave function).

Second question: How correctly calculate offset for color bits array?

Comment: I think instead of `nBitCount >> 3` you actually mean `nBitCount/8`.

Comment: One bit per pixel means one bit per pixel. You are reading three bytes per pixel. You need to read one byte and split it into 8 pixels.

Comment: I am edit code (nBitCount >> 3 => nBitCount / 8). But my problem not solved. And what about: "First question: Why when bit count is 1 there are colors other than black and white? "

Comment: Bit depths less than 16, and 16 with bit compression enabled, determine their colors using an associated array of colors (ie the bitmap's palette), where the bit values are indexes into that array. The array can have any colors in it. So there is nothing requiring a 1bpp bitmap to use only black and white colors.

Comment: Remy Lebeau thank you for your answer. Now I understand why this is so. People tell me what a mistake I admit to the EnumerateBits function.